# Turbolinks, :remote forms and links in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there a way to use something like RoR turbolinks and :remote forms and links in Phoenix?

**UPDATE**

Basically remote forms and links and turbolinks is an **simple approach to build dynamic JavaScript sites** in cases when advanced frameworks like React or Backbone would be an overkill.

What is `:remote` [forms and links](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html), it's a special option for Ruby on Rails form and links helpers that instead of submitting forms and navigating links sends AJAX request to the server, the server in turn respond with some JavaScript and Browser evaluates it.

This technic makes it very **quick and cheap** do JavaScript forms and UI without resorting to advanced frameworks like React or Backbone.

[Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic) is an **quick and cheap** approach to speed-up page transitions in web app without resorting to advanced frameworks like React or Backbone. Instead of re-loading the whole page it just updates its content.

Comment: A short description or a link what turbolinks and :remote forms are would help us to answer your question.

Comment: As Jose once said: Phoenix is so fast that all links are turbolinks.

Comment: @JustMichael Phoenix is fast indeed, but the server and network is not the only one source of latency, **browser** introduces its own latencies too (parsing, JS parsing etc...).

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Just a joke, apparently inappropriate, I apologize for that.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin i created example repo with turbolinks https://github.com/Troush/turbolinks_phoenix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dead simple to use Turbolinks with Phoenix. You don't need to make any changes at all to your forms. Just do this to get up and running with Turbolinks:

1. `npm install --save turbolinks`
2. Add Turbolinks to your `brunch-config.js` in the npm section:

   `npm: {
   enabled: true,
   whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "turbolinks"]
   }`
3. Import turbolinks into your `app.js`:

   `import "phoenix_html"
   import "turbolinks"
   ...`

That's it. You'll get a speed boost across your site without impacting SEO. You can always decide later to change forms to a JSON API or go the full-blown SPA route if you really need to.

Answer (score 3):

Turbolinks is javascript library. You can use it everywhere.
See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/tree/ab019670632b719b3d2ecdccb158ff9f4f47746f#installation-using-webpack
and integrate it similar to brunch.

Install turbolinks `npm install --save turbolinks`

Add `node_modules/turbolinks/dist/tubolinks.js` to your brunch-config.js as dependancy.

Or use webpack with Phoenix http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets#section-using-another-asset-management-system-in-phoenix

UPDATE: Example repo here https://github.com/Troush/turbolinks_phoenix

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the remote forms, you can just write some javascript (or jquery in this case) yourself, something like this:

```
 $("body").on("submit", "form[data-remote='true']", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      method: $form.attr("method"),
      url: $form.attr("action"),
      data: $form.serialize(),
      dataType: "script",
      beforeSend: function(_jqXHR, _settings) {
        // add a loader or whatever
      },
      complete: function(_jqXHR,_textStatus) {
        // remove a loader or whatever
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, already did it. Sadly JS is not enough, you need to specify JS formats in Phoenix Router, handle CSRF tokens and some other minor issues. Would be nice to have all of this stuff out of the box.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Why would you need to handle CSRF tokens?

Comment: if you click on link that result in AJAX post request - you have to pass CSRF token with it.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Can't you just generate it using the `phoenix_html`'s `link()` ? It will generate a link wrapped in a form and then, when the link is clicked, you could just submit the form, which already contains the token.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's a possible way, but then I would have to handle this form specially - intercept its submission and send it as AJAX instead. It's definitely an option, but it seems like just adding a CSRF token to AJAX request directly is an easier way. (But, it's just my preferences, maybe it's not actually the best way to handle it...)

Answer (score 2):

All of Rails's link/form remote magic (and some other nice stuff) happens with this Javascript library:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

I don't see why this wouldn't work with Phoenix (maybe with some tweaks).

Comment: i really miss jquery-ujs in phoenix. what kind of changes should we make so i can use it in phoenix just like rails?